# ReplaySubject it is not updating the array when new object is added Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am dealing with an error which when I try to create new `page` Object, it send to backend but it is not updating the array, I need to reload the page to see the all the array.

I am using Observable within `async` in the frontend.
I tried to console.log the `ngOnInit` of the `page.component.ts` but when I add new page and navigate to pages then the `ngOnInit` it isn't calling.

On Create new page it happens this.
It sends me to the route of `pages` where there I show all the list of pages.
But when I create new `Page` it is returningback an error which says.
`ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'Here is the name of the object'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`.

**Update: as Marco said this happens because I mix page as Object instead I am iterating through array**
But I am unable to resolve it and i need your help.
In the `page.service.ts` at `pageModel` when I add new Object it is returning me only the added `Object` not the whole array and there is the problem I think, but I don't know how to fix.
But If I reload page then I see all my Array.

This is my updated code.

This is my code.

```
  export class PagesService {
  public baseUrl = environment.backend;
  private data = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  public userID = this.authService.userID;
  public editDataDetails: any = [];
  public subject = new Subject<any>();
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.editDataDetails);
  getPageID = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) { }

  public getPages() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/pages/${this.userID}`).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }
  public pageModel(): Observable<Page[]> {
    return this.data.asObservable(); // Here it throws error
  }
  public getPage(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/page/${id}`);
  }

  public setPage(page: Page, id: string) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/page`;
    const user_id = id;
    this.http.post<any>(api, page, {
      headers: { user_id }
    }).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

  public updateDate(id: string, page: Page) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/page/${id}`;
    return this.http.put<any>(api, page).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res.data));
  }
```

Updated Code from Answer.

```
  public updateDate(id: string, page: Page) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/page/${id}`;
    return this.http.put<any>(api, page).subscribe(res => {
      this.lastSetOfData = res;
      this.data.next(this.lastSetOfData);
    });
  }    
}




export class Page {
  _id = "";
  name = "";
  slogan = "";
  description = "";
  url = "";
  telephone: number;
  pageUrl: string;
  website: string;
  founded: number;
  organization: number;
  email: string;
  coverImage: string;
  profileImage: string;
  specialty?: Specialty[];
  branches: Branches[];
  locations?: Location[];
  phone?:Phone;
  userRole?: string;
  roles?: Roles[];
}
export class Roles {
  role= "";
  userID = "";
}
```

This is the HTML of page.component .

```
  <div class="main" *ngIf="!showWeb">
    <div *ngFor="let page of pages$ | async" class="card width-900">
      <app-pages-list class="d-flex width-900" [page]="page" [details]="'details'"></app-pages-list>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the TS file.

```
public pages$: Observable<Page[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {    
this.pageService.getPages();
this.pages$ = this.pageService.pageModel();
}
```

And this is the code when I create new Page.

```
  export class CreatePageComponent implements OnInit {
  public page = new Page();
  search;
  public branch = [];

  constructor(public router: Router,
    public branchesService: BranchesService,
    public authService: AuthService,
      public pageService: PagesService,
      public shareData: SenderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  createPage() {
    this.page.url = this.page.name;
    this.page.branches = this.branch;
    this.page.locations = [];
    this.page.specialty = [];
    this.page.roles = [];
    this.page.phone = this.page.phone;
    this.page.pageUrl = `${this.page.name.replace(/\s/g, "")}${"-Page"}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000)}`;
    this.pageService.setPage(this.page, this.authService.userID);
  }
  addBranch(event) {
      this.branch.push(event);
      this.search = "";
  }
  removeBranch(index) {
      this.branch.splice(index, 1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please improve your question as it is hard to understand clearly. Is there typescript code in your HTML file ? You have a `pages` variables that is never used and never declared. Other variables are never declared.

Comment: I think the problem is that you intialise the array with an empty array. Then, you add items to that array. Angular change detection checks if he needs to rerender by comparing instance. If it's the same array's instance, it won't trigger rerender. I'm not sure if it's the problem because I don't know where to look.

Comment: @Marco I have edited my code and I have deleted the unused code.

Comment: @Marco I have edited my question, added other code which is giving back some error.

Comment: Please settle down on pinging the user. Users may leave comments and never come back. Meanwhile, other users are reading your question and can see you've edited your question (the "edited X units ago" link goes to a page where they can see the entire history of edits if they so desire), so those comments are a bit redundant.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it.
Sorry that made something like this.

Comment: Can you identify clearly the line where the error is thrown ? With a `// Comment.` for example.

Comment: You probably wouldn't have this problem if you'd properly used Types on your service. Now everything is `any` and you are putting objects in places where arrays are expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the one identified in the response from @Marco. I elaborate starting from there.

There are several ways of fixing this problem. Probably the fastest is to add an instance variable `lastSetOfData` to `PagesService` where you hold the last version of the array. Then you initiatlize `lastSetOfData` in the `getPages` method. Finally in the `setPage` method you update `lastSetOfData` appending the Page returned by the service at the end of `lastSetOfData` and notify it using the ReplaySubject.

So the code could look like this

```
export class PagesService {
  public baseUrl = environment.backend;
  // specify the type of data notified by the ReplaySubject
  private data = new ReplaySubject<Array<Page>>();
  // define lastSetOfData as an array of Pages
  private lastSetOfData: Array<Page> = [];
  ....
  public getPages() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/page/${this.userID}`).subscribe(res => {
     // res should be an array of Pages which we use to initialize lastSetOfData
     lastSetOfData = res;
     this.data.next(lastSetOfData)
    });
  }
  ....

  public setPage(page: Page, id: string) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/page`;
    const user_id = id;
    this.http.post<any>(api, page, {
      headers: { user_id }
    }).subscribe(res => {
         // update lastSetOfData appending resp, which should be a Page 
         // not the use of the spread operator ... to create a new Array
         lastSetOfData = [...lastSetOfData, resp];
         // now you notify lastSetOfData
         this.data.next(lastSetOfData)
    });
  }
  // probably you have to modify in a similar way also the method updateTable
  public updateDate(id: string, page: Page) {
    ....
  }
  ....
  ....
}
```

Consider that this may be the fastest way to fix the problem. Check if it works and then you may want to try to refactor the code to look for a more rx-idiomatic solution. But my suggestion is first to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Yeah this is working.
But how would be the code for the `updateDate` which is the edited Object to update ?
Because I tried like this 
`lastSetOfData = res;
     this.data.next(lastSetOfData)` but didnt work.

Comment: What is returned by the `PUT` HTML request ? Certainly the edited item, so you need to remove the old item from your array and then add the edited one (the one returned by the API).

Comment: @Picci Haven't time to elaborate my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Marco @Picci on the update it is saying that.
`core.js:6006 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`

Comment: It's the same problem. Like I said, data is a ReplaySubject of an array and you are giving it only one item. You need to remove the old item and add the new item in the `lastSetOfData` array and then pass it to your subject.

Comment: @Marco and How can i do it ?

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi I added a solution for the `update` in my own answer as the edit queued for the answer of Picci is full.

Comment: @Marco what about `subscribe(res)` the res is unused do we need it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer using `res` instead of `page`. Depend on what `res` is, it might the same thing using `res` or `page`.

Comment: @Marco Whom should I give the bounty poinst ? Because you and Picci did answer correct.

Comment: I think Marco highlighted the point, he is the one who really gave the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding of your code, your error is thrown because the `data` variable hold 2 types of objects.

In the `PagesServices`:

- In `getPages` you give `data` a list of `Page`.
- In `setPage` and `updatePage` you give `data` an instance of `Page`.

```js
private data = new ReplaySubject<any>();
```

When you create a new page, `data` hold the last page you created (not an array). Then you try to iterate this page.

```html
<div *ngFor="let page of pages$ | async"
```

This error come from the fact that you can't iterate a `Page` object.
You should stop using `any` so that this type of error occurs at compilation time, not at runtime. Also you need to store an instance of the array of page, add the item in your array after a post, and then replay the whole array.

Code

```js
public updateDate(id: string, page: Page) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/page/${id}`;
    return this.http.put<any>(api, page).subscribe((res) => {   
        const index: number = lastSetOfData.findIndex((_page: Page) => _page._id === res._id);
        lastSetOfData[index] = res;
        lastSetOfData = [...lastSetOfData];
        this.data.next(lastSetOfData);
    });
}
```

Also the `updateDate` function should be named `updatePage`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what would be your idea ?
Can you write some code that I can see what are you thinking ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you put an object in your replaysubject although an array is expected in other places.

```
next(myarray)
next(myobject)
```

This does not magically append an object to the array.

To do so, you'd need something like this:

```
data.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(list => {
    list.push(newvalue);
    data.next(list);
});
```

Basically you take the last value, a the new item, and push the new list.